# How to create link in content element

Tags: html, css

I have been tasked with creating this.

[image: Expired message]

I can create the box, font-awesome icon and the non-linking text using a pseudo element content, but I am unable to create the Learn More link (with a span class to include the >).

If I add text directly into the html, it will not fill the box (and spills out below it).  I would also be forced to use inline styles to keep it top-aligned with the !.

We want to keep this in the CSS if at all possible.  I realize that the real answer is that you can't do it, but I'm looking for a workaround to make it work.

This is the CSS I can use to place the non-linking message:

```
    &:after {
        color: #7b7b7b;
        margin-top: -43px;
        padding-left: 19%;
        line-height: 18px;
        display: flex;
        font-weight: normal;
        content: "You are no longer on FPC, you will now be back to your regular contract.";

        @media #{$small} {
            padding-left: 15%;
            margin-top:-37px;
        }
    }

    &:before {
        color: #7b7b7b;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

And this is the line of HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Learn more <span class="arrow-right"></span></a>
```

Does anyone have a solution to help me make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the generated CSS instead of the SCSS? It's not clear what `&` is referring to, in this scenario.  Part of the problem is that your opening span tag needs to look like this: `<span class="fa fa-arrow-right">`

Comment: @AlexW the arrow-right is a variable set up previously as it's used many places, and it works fine.  The &:after is also established in the bootstrap code to represent the pseudo elements (which was hacked a few ways by one of our main developers - for example, the media #{$small} is actually referring to the desktop version)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different structure & CSS if you end up going in that direction.

```css
.message {
  border: 2px solid #7b7b7b;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: #f7fcff;
  padding: 7px 8px 5px 42px;
}

.message>.message-icon {
  position: absolute;
  color: #7b7b7b;
  font-size: 26px;
  left: 10px;
}

p {
  color: #7b7b7b;
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}

a {
  color: #1464ae;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a .action-icon {
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="message">
  <span class="message-icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i></span>
  <p>You are no longer on FPC, you will now be back to your regular contract.</p>
  <a href="">Learn More
    <span class="action-icon"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: With your snippet, it appears that may work.  I'll try it in the morning, and report back.